getting, java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child, in Tomcat 10
I am trying to start my deployed application on Tomcat 10, but getting java.lang. IllegalStateException: Error starting child error in Catalina.out file. If I downgrade the Tomcat version to 9, I am able to start my application, but due to Spring Boot version 3 (JakartaEE) require Tomcat 10. But what is wrong here? I am working on multiple module rest APIs. Having three application parent, internal, model and persistence. if I run the internal with embedded tomcat server I am getting proper response.
Tomcat Home Page Error Message
FAIL - Application at context path [/Internal] could not be started
FAIL - Encountered exception [org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Internal]]]

Catalina Log
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:698)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:747)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1027)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:2001)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:572)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:828)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:478)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1708)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:320)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:946)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:886)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:265)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:795)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:476)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Internal]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:726)
        ... 35 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:165)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:619)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:174)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:154)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:96)
        at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5169)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        ... 36 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to register 'filter errorPageFilterRegistration' on the servlet context. Possibly already registered?
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.DynamicRegistrationBean.register(DynamicRegistrationBean.java:122)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.RegistrationBean.onStartup(RegistrationBean.java:52)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.selfInitialize(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:241)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:197)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:162)
        ... 47 more


I am adding all 3 modules inside Parent POM and building parent application
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.4</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.parent</groupId>
    <artifactId>Parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>Parent</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot Modules</description>
    <url />
    <licenses>
        <license />
    </licenses>
    <developers>
        <developer />
    </developers>
    <scm>
        <connection />
        <developerConnection />
        <tag />
        <url />
    </scm>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <modules>
        <module>../model</module>
        <module>../persistence</module>
        <module>../Internal</module>

    </modules>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>

                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

</project>


Internal POM file. In tomcat I am deploying the Internal application generated war file. bcz controller placed here.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.parent</groupId>
        <artifactId>Parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../Parent/pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>Internal</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Internal</name>

    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot Modules</description>
    <url />
    <licenses>
        <license />
    </licenses>
    <developers>
        <developer />
    </developers>
    <scm>
        <connection />
        <developerConnection />
        <tag />
        <url />
    </scm>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.parent</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.parent</groupId>
            <artifactId>model</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.springTech.internal.InternalApplication</mainClass>
                    <layout>WAR</layout>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>


Model application POM file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.parent</groupId>
        <artifactId>Parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../Parent/pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>model</artifactId>
    <name>model</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot Modules/model</description>
    <url />
    <licenses>
        <license />
    </licenses>
    <developers>
        <developer />
    </developers>
    <scm>
        <connection />
        <developerConnection />
        <tag />
        <url />
    </scm>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>


persistence Application POM file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.parent</groupId>
        <artifactId>Parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../Parent/pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>persistence</artifactId>
    <name>persistence</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot Modules</description>

    <url />
    <licenses>
        <license />
    </licenses>
    <developers>
        <developer />
    </developers>
    <scm>
        <connection />
        <developerConnection />
        <tag />
        <url />
    </scm>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.parent</groupId>
            <artifactId>model</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>


Internal code blocks
package com.springTech.internal;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import com.springTech.model.entity.Users;
import com.springTech.persistence.repo.UserRepo;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.springTech")
public class InternalApplication implements CommandLineRunner  {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(InternalApplication.class, args);
    }
    
    @Autowired
    private UserRepo repo;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        Users u = new Users();
        u.setUserName("aman");
        repo.save(u);
        
        Users u1 = new Users();
        u1.setUserName("Dev");
        repo.save(u1);
    }

}


package com.springTech.internal.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.springTech.internal.service.UserService;
import com.springTech.model.entity.Users;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@RestController
@Slf4j
public class UserController {
    
    @Autowired
    UserService service;
    
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserController.class);

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String sayHi() {
        return "Hi";
    }

    @GetMapping("/user")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getAllUsers() {
        try {
            List<Users> users = service.getAllUser();
            return ResponseEntity.ok(users);  
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error fetching users", e.fillInStackTrace());  
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                                 .body("An error occurred while retrieving users."); 
        }
    }

}

package com.springTech.internal.serviceImpl;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.springTech.internal.service.UserService;
import com.springTech.model.entity.Users;
import com.springTech.persistence.repo.UserRepo;

@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    UserRepo userRepo;
    
    
    @Override
    public List<Users> getAllUser() {
        return userRepo.findAll();
    }

}

Model code blocks
package com.springTech.model.entity;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Users")
@Data
@Getter
@Setter
public class Users {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="user_id")
    private Integer userId;
    
    @Column(name="user_name")
    private String userName;

    public Integer getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(Integer userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

}

Persistence code blocks
package com.springTech.persistence.repo;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.springTech.model.entity.Users;


public interface UserRepo extends JpaRepository<Users, Integer> {

}

Persistence DB config
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.h2.console.enabled=true

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update



This question is similar to: Failed to register 'filter errorPageFilterRegistration' on the servlet context. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Only your war project should be build using the spring-boot-maven-plugin all others should be regular jars. I also don't get why you declared your dependencies in the parent instead of the childs as not every project needs spring-boot-starter-web or spring-boot-starter-data-jpa. Change your @SpringBootApplication to @SpringBootApplication(basePackage="com.springTech") and remove the other annotations.

@M.Deinum, I edited my code as you suggested and also updated the above code blocks. Getting same error. Able to run Internal without any problem with the embed tomcat

I don't see an ServletContextIntializer in your code, which is needed to start the application.

Sorry, I haven't added it here, while creating the spring boot application, parallel to the main class one seperate ServletContextIntializer, created by default for all the projects.

Finally found the solution for my problem. I downgraded the version of Spring from <version>3.3.4</version> to <version>3.0.13</version> in my parent POM.xml file. But I am not sure why it's not working for the higher version.
